# Downcasting in Inheritance

Tags: java

I understand that upcasting/downcasting in objects do not change the object, but rather change how we deal with them. ( or change the type of their reference if I understand correctly).

However, if we have an Animal class that has a getName(); method, and a dog class which is a child class of Animal.

```
Animal Billy = new Animal("billy",1);
Dog b = (Dog)Billy;
b.getName();
```

I understand that it will compile, but give a run time error, my question is why, getName(); method is present in the Animal Class, and so it is inherited by the Dog class, so it's present in both, what prevents us from having it done?

Comment: The first problem is that `Animal` is apparently not an abstract class. There goes your entire hierarchy. You should follow a tutorial on OOP first, they have this exact situation everywhere.

Comment: Because `(Dog)` verifies that the object is, in fact a `Dog`.  The cast generates (I think it's called) a CastClassCheck bytecode, and that bytecode throws a cast check exception if the referenced object is not a `Dog` or some subclass of a `Dog`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Why does Animal have to be an abstract class??

Comment: @HotLicks: because it is a non-sensical class. There is no such thing as an 'animal', it's just a common term for all kinds of subclasses that lead to a specific animal. Making an instance of 'animal' makes no sense.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - There most certainly is such a thing as an Animal.  Or would you insist that Dog be broken down into Affenpinscher, IrishWolfhound, SiberianHusky, EnglishSetter, and 600 other breeds?

Comment: @HotLicks: yes, *if* that's where it ends: subclasses of dog. That would be the same if an animal was also the end node of the tree here. But it isn't: there is a subclass of type `Dog`. You can't instantiate a common denominator when there is a more specific one inside the tree, that causes ambiguity.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - You have a very narrow understanding of OOP.  Quit reading from the book and get some actual experience.

Comment: @HotLicks: in order to avoid going too far here in the comments, I've created [a question over on Programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/252142/should-an-animal-be-abstract-or-allow-for-instantiation-to-represent-a-general). I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: @HotLicks Nothing to do with this question, but *if* I'd already specified a class such as `Dog` I would very much *consider* making `Animal` an abstract class. It's certainly not a requirement though, as Jeroen suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you downcast check it first using [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator.

```
Animal billy = new Animal("billy",1);

if (billy instanceof Dog) {
    Dog b = (Dog) billy;
    b.getName();
}
```

since `Animal` can be any thing `Cat`, `Dog` etc. It's not known at compile time hence before downcast you have to check it.

---

> `getName()` method is present in the `Animal` Class, and so it is inherited by the `Dog` class, so it's present in both, what prevents us from having it done?

Nothing prevent you but you have to do as shown below.

If `getName()` method is present in `Animal` class then there is no need to downcast just call it on the reference of `Animal` class and the actual `getName()` method of `Dog` class will be called.

```
Animal billy = new Dog("billy",1);
billy.getName();
```

Read more about [Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

[image]

Comment: +1 Amazing illustration :)

Comment: Of course, the `instanceof` check is unnecessary if you *know* that the Animal reference is *actually* referencing a Dog.  The cast operation provides a sort of "assertion check" in the event of a bug that has caused that to not be the case.  You only need the `instanceof` check in the event that you're not sure.

Comment: Brilliant. I do understand the material, overloading, overiding,etc, but I was interested in that case, because I've to do code tracing, and was playing around with things. Thanks a lot for you, and everyone for the great help.

Comment: "Whenever you downcast check it first using instanceof operator" That is very poor advice. If followed as a rule, it will hide many errors.

Comment: @Boann Read more what I have suggested. So you want to say in next version of Java, `isntanceof` operator should be removed. Why `instanceof` operator is made for. Please I want to know.

Comment: @Boann how downcasting will work in Java.

Comment: I read the rest of your answer but it doesn't change the fact that the first part of it is giving very poor advice. If you require the Animal to be a Dog, it is correct to throw the ClassCastException. If we follow the advice in your question, the code will *silently do the wrong thing*. "So you want to say in next version of Java, isntanceof operator should be removed." I never said that. I said that it is wrong to use it "whenever you downcast".

Comment: @Boann please post your answer to make it for clear for other as well as me. Finally it's your opinion. Suggest which is best and correct advice.

Comment: @user3218114 The correct answer was already given by Hot Licks in the comments: "Because (Dog) verifies that the object is, in fact a Dog". I really don't understand why you can't see the problem with your answer. Do you really want code to go around *silently ignoring errors*? Yuck.